# Laravel Controller ignore if request true or false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have in my Controller this code and try it before with `true` and `false` and `0` and `1`, laravel ignore it.
Now i have changed it to `1 and 2`

```
if ($request->inactive == 1)
```

and

```
if ($request->active== 2)
```

But Laravel gives now an blank page, know anyone why?

Comment: Check for the errors in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also, please show result of `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Laravel dont have log this Error. I have checked it

Comment: as @AlexeyMezenin said, show result of dd($request->all());

Comment: What exact is $request->active/inactive representing?  Is it boolean? 1 represents TRUE and 0 represents FALSE and in your case you may use either to compare.  2 does nothing in this situation unless 2 literally means the integer value 2.

Answer (score 0):

First, die and dump you request to make sure you are getting an input when the box is checked:

```
dd($request->all());
```

HTML checkboxes are a tricky beast.  Basically, if they are checked, they will send a value in the request, otherwise, they will not. By default a checkbox sends the value of 'on' when checked though you can modify this to any value you like, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" value="1"/>
```

Again, if they are not checked, it WILL NOT appear in your request.

In your controller, you may check if the box is checked/input exists by simply doing the following:

```
if(!$request->active) {
    //code if unchecked
} else {
    //code if checked
}
```

This executes specific code depending on if the checkbox is checked or not.